# How to set the default vertex count to added geometry?

Tags: mesh, customization

I wanted to know whether there is a way to set the default amount of vertices of added geometry (Such as default circles and cylinders) ? 
Changing the amount from 32 can get quite annoying as I am working quite a lot with subdivision modeling...

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK it's already hardcoded into Blender, set as default value for each operators creating primitive objects like [a circle](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add). One way to get around this is to add new menu to access these operators, but with different default value. I made a sample code below, also downloadable [here](https://gist.github.com/adhihargo/5962151/download).

When this code is put to a file, opened in Blender's text area and executed, or installed as an addon (after uncommenting `bl_info` block), it will insert a new submenu to **Add**, containing some primitive operators but with different default value upon execution:

[image: Low Vertex Mesh]

There might be simpler ways, but this is the only workaround I know.

```
import bpy

# bl_info = {
#     "name": "Low Vertex Count Objects",
#     "author": "",
#     "version": (1, 0),
#     "blender": (2, 63, 0),
#     "location": "View3D > Add",
#     "description": "Add primitive object with low initial vertex count",
#     "warning": "",
#     "wiki_url": "",
#     "tracker_url": "",
#     "category": "Add Mesh"}

def custom_object_add(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu("INFO_MT_low_vertex_mesh_add", icon='PLUGIN')

class INFO_MT_low_vertex_mesh_add(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = "INFO_MT_low_vertex_mesh_add"
    bl_label = "Low Vertex Mesh"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        prop = layout.operator("mesh.primitive_circle_add", icon='MESH_CIRCLE', text="Circle (12)")
        prop.vertices = 12

        prop = layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cone_add", icon='MESH_CONE', text="Cone (12)")
        prop.vertices = 12

        prop = layout.operator("mesh.primitive_cylinder_add", icon='MESH_CYLINDER', text="Cylinder (12)")
        prop.vertices = 12

        prop = layout.operator("mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add", icon='MESH_UVSPHERE', text="UV Sphere (8x4)")
        prop.segments = 8
        prop.ring_count = 4

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_add.append(custom_object_add)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_add.remove(custom_object_add)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to override the defaults like so:

```
from bpy.props import IntProperty
from bpy.types import (
    MESH_OT_primitive_circle_add,
    MESH_OT_primitive_cylinder_add,
    MESH_OT_primitive_uv_sphere_add,
)

MESH_OT_primitive_circle_add.vertices = IntProperty(name="Vertices", default=16)
MESH_OT_primitive_cylinder_add.vertices = IntProperty(name="Vertices", default=16)
MESH_OT_primitive_uv_sphere_add.segments = IntProperty(name="Segments", default=16)
MESH_OT_primitive_uv_sphere_add.ring_count = IntProperty(name="Rings", default=8)
```

Save in [`scripts/startup/`](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout) with a `.py` file extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CreaPrim addon to create a new (low poly) primitive for you (so you don't have to write the script yourself). To do so:

1. Enable the CreaPrim addon in your settings.
2. Create your circle mesh
3. Select your mesh and in the toolbar scroll down to the CreaPrim panel:

   [image: creaprim toolbar]
4. Name your circle.
5. Click CreaPrim.
6. The primitive is now an add-on which you can enable in your preferences (you may want to create a new file, enable the add-on and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to update the default settings).

**Note: If you get an error when trying to create the primitive (like I did) you may have to use a cylinder instead of a circle. I think there's a bug that doesn't allow you to create one vertex thick meshes**

Comment: What is that Retopo button under Cell Fracture? (I haven't got one)

Comment: It's for grease pencil retopology (addon that you can enable in the settings).