# What is the easiest way to smooth the intersection of two planes?

Tags: modeling, mesh

What is the easiest way to smooth the intersection of two planes as shown in the picture below?

[image: two plains]

I would like to achieve something like:

[image: smoother intersection]

For example, a method I would like to do is to fit a parabola to three lines of two planes and use this parabola to make round corner?

I know this is probably a trivial question, but I am a beginner.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-curved-plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a plane, enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and select one of the edges.

[image]

**Extrude** (<kbd>E</kbd>) and pull up in the z axis.

[image]

Select the edge at the intersection and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> to activate the **Bevel** tool. Moving the mouse will show the effect of the bevel.  Control the amount of cuts with the mouse wheel.
(or you can use the controls found on the toolshelf)

[image][image][image]

Comment: Is there a way to make one half with different texture than the other, but thanks for the answer. This works for me.

Comment: @BlenderPirate feel free to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to separate the each of two planes into two at the line of intersection, and recombine them, so that the part of the horizontal plane to the left of the line of intersection and the part of the other plane above the line of intersection are part of the same plane, and the parts remaining from the original plane are part of the other. Now you can smooth the two planes, and use loop cuts to control the size of the rounded corners.