# Easy way to smooth the intersection of two planes with Python script?

Tags: modeling, scripting, mesh

I was looking not so long time ago how to solve this problem:

[What is the easiest way to smooth the intersection of two planes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13919/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-smooth-the-intersection-of-two-planes)

I received a very nice solution from cegaton, but I am struggling to implement a script version of it. I would like vary angle of the two planes and bevel level.

I would really appreciate if you could help me with scripting of cegatons solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why script it when you can use a bevel modifier and bevel weights?

Comment: I am generating database of different scenes. I need to script it.

Comment: Is what you want possible with the modifier? If so, just script the adding of the modifier ;)

Comment: If you could help me with that please, but I think it is more complicated than the solution in the previous post.