# How to split a beveled surface to two parts to use different materials

Tags: python, mesh, materials

Recently I asked this question and got a very nice answer:

[What is the easiest way to smooth the intersection of two planes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13919/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-smooth-the-intersection-of-two-planes)

However, now I would like to use a different material for each face. Could anybody help me on how to do this? Written in python script would be best.

Thanks,
Mojmir.

Comment: Would you be willing to use a subdivision surface with "control loops" ? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQZ5ZAldzu4 (I couldn't find a text article that explains the technique in my time quota).  Solving it in python would require about 30 minutes of analytic geometry and 30 minutes of futzing with bmesh.

Comment: You can directly set the material of a face. [api docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.material_index)

Comment: pink vertex: Yes that is true but how do I select the face? Where are they located I was trying but they are not as edges. One cannot do obj.data.faces[i] like with edges obj.data.edges[i]

Answer (score 1):

No script here but this is a possible node setup:
[image]

to get this:
[image]