# Curving an existing flat plane

Tags: modeling

Normally, when one creates a curved surface, I understand that you
would add a curve, finalize the shape and then extrude it. I'd like to
convert an existing surface to a curved one - in this case, the selected area of a 
furniture leg piece that I'd like to curve inwards. Ideas? thanks

[image]

Comment: You may use a Lattice Modifier. The adequate solution to the one you're asking for is here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Modifiers/Lattice/Shaping_a_Fork

Comment: ..Or create two identical curves of desired shape, place them on the same width as the width of the mesh, convert curves to mesh and join them. You can then substitute mesh parts with those curves and create faces with *Bridge Edge Loops*.

Comment: @Gonzou - thanks.. love the lattice modifier

Comment: @MrZak - do you have a link to somewhere that demonstrates the technique? thanks

Comment: Of course, related to your question - http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5625/1245. The last thing to do will be to join made shape with your furniture piece.

Comment: @RoyM you'll love it even more when you know all its possibilities ;). I'm glad I helped.