# Water in a glass bottle error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to simulate water in a glass bottle. For some reason there seems to be some refraction that causes the water to bend upwards and creates a weird effect(a sort of upwards bump).

Can anyone please shed some light on this situation and explain why this is happening?

I have also attached the blend file below:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6385EC1FC28C8087!337&authkey=!AGWj45uZHzTciRo&ithint=file%2cblend

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That all looks physically accurate. Realize that the bottle acts as a lense, so it distorts things behind it

Comment: While I understand that some distortion should occur, I have seen other results on the internet that don't have that weird bump. Scaling the water object doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I think that is a reflection on the bottle

Comment: Reflection? I don't quite follow. Is there any way to get rid of this reflection? Thanks.

Comment: What is happening is completely expected given your scene. I think you should instead focus on replicating a product photography scene. Cycles is a physically based render engine, so things work best if you don't try to fake basic things like reflections.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I was replicating a product photography scene. Thing is, I'm not trying to fake reflections. I did change the IOR of the glass shader to that of water. However, all I can think of at this point is that perhaps I should try another shader to simulate water, but even mixing different shaders like diffuse and transparency do not give convincing results.

Comment: related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/liquid-glass-interface-ior-and-normals-in-cycles

Comment: Hi, could you please upload your blend file to [BlendExchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)? We prefer that you use this, because the files don't get deleted, so people who find your question later can still use all of it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ is right, those refractions look normal to me.

Comment: If you don't like them, perhaps adding [a backdrop](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5623/599) will get something closer to what you want. Here's [an example render](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LjdPL.png)

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be happening is the light is hitting the bottom of the glass, going through it, and then reflecting upwards hitting the top of the bottle, creating a weird reflection. The reflection changes based on the angle you look at the object.

I'm pretty sure that this is working how it's supposed to. It just looks weird to the eye. There are a few things you could check/do to fix it though.

- Check to see if the liquid, is touching the glass. This is known to cause artifacts.
- You could change the camera position or lighting to make it less
  apparent.
- You could also adjust light bounces in the light paths drop down in
  the render panel. (this would decrease the realism, but you could lower the bounces so that the light doesn't reflect enough times to cause that reflection)

[I think you might benefit from this tutorial.](https://youtu.be/Xbc3KMIOuKM?t=1097) I linked it at the point where he started doing the liquid.