# How to curve the edges of a plane?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I've been looking around and i haven't quite found a way to do this yet without going through a lot of trouble.. I'm trying to curve a plane. To be clear,i'm not trying to do this: [What is the fastest way to create a curved plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-curved-plane)

What i'm trying to do, is this:
[image: Single inwards curve]

What i want to do is put inward curves on all 4 edges, and possibly a curve on 'top' of the plane as well. I managed to get one inwards curve by using the Curve Modifier, but i haven't managed to get multiple curves at once by using this. also, it messes up the rest of the plane when i do that. So, is there a way to do this?

P.S. For anyone who wants to know, i'm trying to make a shadesail for a 3D house project. The last time i did a shadesail, I made it manually and it took **AGES** so i'm just trying to find a way around this problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** This is non destructive way to do such thing. You can always use
>   **Proportional Editing** to directly model this shape.

1. Add a **Plane** and **Subdivide** it as much as you need/want.

[image: 1]

2. Add **Lattice** and **Scale** it by **2**.
3. Go to **Lattice Data tab** and set **U: 3**, **V: 3**, **W: 1**.

[image: 2]

4. Add **Lattice modifier** to the **Plane** and choose **Lattice** as **Object**.

[image: 3]

5. Go back to **Lattice** in **Edit Mode**, select needed vertices and **Scale** them down and also move center vertex on the **Z axis**.

[image]

**Blend file:**

[image]

Comment: You sir, are a hero. You have changed my life. Thanks man, this is exactly what i was trying to do! :D

Answer (score 1):

Add a Plane and sub divide it to 8 and then 2 subdivide again to get a smooth

Add Empty

With the plane selected Add a Cast Modifier

In the control object select Empty

And with the empty selected pull up or down to get the shape

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Circle. SHIFT + "A" and select "Circle" from the drop down menu.

TAB into Edit Mode and extrude inwards. Press "E" + "S" SHIFT "Z".

[image]

Then delete unwanted vertices by selecting them and pressing "X".

[image]

**EDIT:**
Another option.

Add a Plane. SHIFT +"A" select Mesh > Plane from the drop down menu.

TAB into Edit Mode. Add some Loop Cuts. CTRL + "R" > Mouse Wheel to increase the number of Loop Cuts.

[image]

TAB into Object Mode and press "A" to deselect the plane.

Add a Bezier Circle. SHIFT +"A" select Curve > Circle from the drop down menu.

[image]

Select the Plane and add a Curve Modifier. Choose the BezierCircle as the Object in the Curve Modifier Pane.

[image]

Select the Bezier Circle and press "S" to adjust the scale.

[image]

You can also select the plane and adjust it's scale 0n the "X" axis (in this example.

[image]

Comment: I thought of that, but then i would have to add 4 circles, delete all the unwanted parts, and join them together again; then i'd have to reshape the entire thing to fit the curve that i'm trying to get. That would basically take just as long as my original method... I was hoping this could be done with the curve modifier somehow...

Comment: I'm confused... 4 circles, delete, join?

Comment: Ok, i'll try explain... Basically, i need this- https://db1736767dbd5e7094bb-d61bbc5d0b342a54145a236e2d5d1ebf.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/Product-800x800/d25decc8-2651-495b-9c5b-29e3bf2b2900.jpg --thats a shadesail. All 4 sides of the square curve inwards. Using the method above, I can only get one side to curve inwards. I've been trying to use multiple curve modifiers on one mesh but so far...nada. If I was able to use 4 or more curve modifiers on one mesh,then there would be no problem.