# Creating cup base

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

How can I create only the base of a cup, with no sharp edges?

I want to make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSp0r.png) (image taken from [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5628)), but rotated around the leftmost point.

The end result will look something like a bowl.

I want to use this as the background for studio lighting.

Either a manual or scripted approach is ok.

Comment: if you create a cylinder, select the bottom edge, and ctrl B to bevel it, it will create a round angle, is it what you want?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Create a vertex extrude it to make an "L" (far left model)

Teke the middle vertex and bevel it using Ctrl + Shift + B or Ctrl + B and then V (middle model)

Go in object mode and apply a screw modifier, make sure your origin point is on the far left vertex, in the middle of the screwing process (far right model)

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a Bézier curve where you can control the overall shape, and convert it finally into a mesh. Then you use the Screw modifier as above.