How to make a seamless curved backdrop?
How do I make a seamless curved backdrop to be used for product placement?

Strictly speaking, this question would unfortunately have to be closed here, because it allows not just one useful answer, but a multitude of answers. I would therefore ask you to be a little more precise in your question, and perhaps also to mention what you have tried so far or what you are specifically failing at.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63033/how-to-create-an-infinite-plane-in-cycles/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-a-curved-plane/162833#162833

If you need a 360 shot, add a circle, extrude its outer edges upwards and shade it smooth. Then add a bevel modifier to it.

In the Bevel modifier, check harden normals to avoid interpolation along the large planar base.
Choose "Weight" as Limit Method to control the bevel via edges.
(Select an edge and go to the menu Edge > Bevel Weight.)



Add a plane. ShiftA
Go into edit mode. Tab
Select an edge 2 / Mousebutton and extrude Eit upwards.Z
Select the outer edges. ShiftMousebutton
Crease them. ShiftE > 1 > Confirm
Add a subdivision surface modifier in object mode. Ctrl3
Set it to shade smooth. W > Shade Smooth


