# Error overriding default property for MESH_OT_primitive_torus_add?

Tags: python

Following this Stack Exchange page:

[How to set the default vertex count to added geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1745/how-to-set-the-default-vertex-count-to-added-geometry)

I was able to effectively override the default property for the circle, cylinder and UV sphere.

When I followed the exact principle, imported the MESH_OT for torus primitive and try to override its defaults, blender fails at importing its MESH_OT module.

Code:

```
from bpy.types import (
    MESH_OT_primitive_torus_add
    )
```

According to Blender, this can not be imported, I fail to understand why!

If anyone has experience with this and has successfully done so, please lend a hand.

Here is a screenshot of the error message:
[image]

Comment: How exactly did you override in this case?

Comment: It's pretty clearly demonstrated in the link to the other post.  I did exactly the same.

Comment: Have a look at `2.78/scripts/startup/bl_operators/add_mesh_torus.py`  You can `from bl_operators.add_mesh_torus import AddTorus` change default params and re-regisiter.  Btw the [stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/qu...added-geometry) link above returns a 404, as it is the condensed ( "blah...blah") version.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much.  Importing from bl_operators worked!  I'm still curious about what's the principal behind it.  There seem to be a big difference between the torus and other primitives of how they are created?  PS: I have no clue why the page went offline.  I got to see it yesterday for the method.  @batFINGER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be where you are trying to do the import, I expect the script you are adding is read too early to get access to `bpy.types`. While there is a way to alter the default setting, it doesn't seem to effect creating new objects, my guess is that the presets system overrides the defaults.

If you are adding a torus with a python script you can set the parameters used in your script.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_torus_add(major_segments=12, minor_segments=8)
```

For adding objects manually, the best way I can see is to use the presets system. You do this by adding a torus, then use the [operator properties panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/undo_and_redo.html#ui-redo-last) to adjust the options used, then click the <kbd>+</kbd> next to operator Presets and give it a name.

[image: name a preset]

then your preset options will be available.

[image: operator properties with presets]

Comment: Thank you for this.  I know there are presets, but I wanted a way using script.

Comment: You can specify settings to a bpy.ops call, to change the defaults that are used when you manually add a torus you will need to alter add_mesh_torus.py, or replace the operator with your own. Even if you change the apparent default with `bpy.types.MESH_OT_primitive_torus_add.major_segments[1]['default'] = 12` it isn't used when you add a torus, it appears that the presets override the default settings.

Comment: I'm already able to override the properties using the method commented in the question by @batFINGER.  I will mark your answer as approved to close this question.